# Python re.search function regex issue

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time, uuid, hmac, hashlib, base64, json
import urllib3
import certifi
import datetime
import requests
import re
from datetime import datetime

http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', # Force certificate check.
    ca_certs=certifi.where(),  # Path to the Certifi bundle.
)

#Get the status response from pritunl api
BASE_URL = 'https://www.vpn.trimble.cloud:443'
API_TOKEN = 'gvwrfQZQPryTbX3l03AQMwTyaE0aFywE'
API_SECRET = 'B0vZp5dDyOrshW1pmFFjAnIUyeGtFy9y'
LOG_PATH = '/var/log/developer_vpn/'
def auth_request(method, path, headers=None, data=None):
    auth_timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    auth_nonce = uuid.uuid4().hex
    auth_string = '&'.join([API_TOKEN, auth_timestamp, auth_nonce,
        method.upper(), path] + ([data] if data else []))
    auth_signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(
        API_SECRET, auth_string, hashlib.sha256).digest())
    auth_headers = {
        'Auth-Token': API_TOKEN,
        'Auth-Timestamp': auth_timestamp,
        'Auth-Nonce': auth_nonce,
        'Auth-Signature': auth_signature,
    }
    if headers:
        auth_headers.update(headers)
    return http.request(method, BASE_URL + path, headers=auth_headers, body=data)


response1 = auth_request('GET',
  '/server',
)
if response1.status == 200:
    pritunlServResponse = (json.loads(response1.data))
    #print pritunlServResponse
    #print response1.data

    Name = [y['name'] for y in pritunlServResponse]
    Server_id = [x['id'] for x in pritunlServResponse]

    for srv_name, srv_id in zip(Name, Server_id):
        response2 = auth_request('GET',
        '/server/' + srv_id + '/output',
        )
        pritunlServResponse2 = (json.loads(response2.data))
        py_pritunlServResponse2 = pritunlServResponse2['output']

        print("value of srv_id: ", srv_id, "\n")
        print("value of srv_name: ", srv_name, "\n") 

        logfile = open(LOG_PATH + srv_name +'_vpn_out.log', 'w')
        for log in py_pritunlServResponse2:
            if re.search(r'(?!52\.39\.62\.8)', log):
                logfile.write("%s\n" % log)

        logfile.close()

else:
    raise SystemExit
```

This code visits a website using authentication (the address has been redacted), grabs some text formatted in JSON, and parses two values from the output: "srv_name" and "srv_id". This code then uses the "srv_id" to construct additional HTTP requests to get log files from the server. It then grabs the log files - one for each "srv_id" and names them with the values obtained from "srv_name" and saves them on the local system.

I want to do some additional grep-style processing before the files are written to the local system. Specifically I'd like to exclude any text exactly containing "52.39.62.8" from being written. When I run the code above, it looks like the regex is not being processed as I still see "52.39.62.8" in my output files.

Answer (score 1):

If the IP address is always flanked by specific characters, e.g.: `(52.39.62.8):`, you can use `in` for exact contains:

```
if '(52.39.62.8):' not in log:
    logfile.write(log + '\n')
```

Comment: The brackets are a good guard against false positives, but the original code did not attempt to avoid them, so `if '52.39.62.8' not in log:` would accomplish what the OP seems to have had in mind, simply and elegantly.  (Of course, the program will then also not print e.g. 152.39.62.8 or 52.39.62.81.)

Answer (score 0):

```
re.search(r'(?!52\.39\.62\.8)', log)
```

You're matching *any* empty string that is not followed by the ip address - every string will match, as this will match the end of any string.

reverse your logic and output the line to the log only if `re.search` for the ip address comes back as `None`.

```
if re.search(r'(?<!\d)52\.39\.62\.8(?!\d)', log) is None:
    logfile.write("%s\n" % log)
```

note that this also includes it's own negative look-behind and look-ahead assertions to ensure no digits precede or follow the ip address.

Comment: full disclosure: this was done on my phone and so has not been tested